# I got stuck in this error. How to change version of python on anaconda in proper way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I want to install tensorflow on python version = 3.5. So, when i tried to downgrade version from 3.7 to 3.5 through this command `conda install python=3.5` , It returns these errors:

[image]

Comment: Hi @raobabar, welcome to StackOverFlow. You shouldn't paste an image of an error, instead a text would be much better. Further more, you should write what have you tried before you post the question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downgrading the base environment, you could create a new Python 3.5 environment:

```
conda create --name py35 python=3.5
```

Then activate it with `conda activate py35`.

Comment: Good answer, except the command is `conda activate py35`, not just `activate py35` :-)

Comment: Just `activate {env}` has always worked for me on Windows in the past--is that an installation option?  It's been a while since I've installed it.

Comment: As of conda 4.4 (Dec. 2017), the command on all platforms is the same, `conda activate <env name>`. They still support the old way for backwards compatibility, but might as well use the newer way! Then the answer can be generic :-)